# How to limit user registration to a certain city - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, user-registration

I'm doing administration for a website where users can register and play arcade games. Top 3 best players get the prize from shopping mall which owns the site.
The thing is, I'm getting many spam registrations and I want to limit registrations to a city where the mall is located. Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Lazar

Comment: Can you provide a site link?

Comment: You can use `https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php` but city provided is not 100% accurate. If your ISP is in the next city so are you. Also, IPs can be faked, so it's not a bulletproof solution. Instead of limiting it to the city I'd do as Eduardo says in an answer, use a captcha to keep bots away.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution to avoid "bots"/"spam", is to use a captcha system.

Here is a plugin for that:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-recaptcha-integration/

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the client is asking that users only can register from his city because hi will send gifts to the most active users.